# XML creation with c#

Tags: c#, xml

First off here is my code.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> targetDirectory =
    from XElement e in workingXmlDocument.Descendants(wixNS + "Directory")
    where e.Attribute("Id").Value == "TARGETDIR"
    select e;
foreach (var now in targetDirectory)
{
    now.Add(XElement.Parse("<Directory Id='" + fileVariable.Directory.Name 
                                             + @"' />"));
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to search for every Directory element with the attribute Id valued at TARGETDIR. Then I place a new directory element inside that one with a name of a file's directory. It does just that. The problem is that it just puts all the directories into a single line (no line breaks, no indent, nothing, just the raw data), and it includes a blank xmlns tag with every element. How do I tell it that each element should have it's own line in the XML document and how do I tell it to use the same namespace as the rest of the document? I know I could just explicitly tell it that it should have a xmlns attribute with the correct NS, but that is the last thing I want to do. ideas?

**Update - the code for the XML Writer**

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;

using (XmlWriter currentWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
{
     workingXmlDocument.WriteTo(currentWriter);
     currentWriter.Flush();
} // using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(FilePath))
```

From here it is not adding new lines to the included elements from the above code.

Comment: (I've reformatted to make it clear that the foreach loop isn't part of the query.)

Comment: Why is that the last thing you want to do? That's kinda how XML works.

Comment: @Jeff Yates - normally when I am working with WiX and XML in general if I only have one namespace in a file there is no need to have the xmlns attribute on every single element that is in it.  Normally it is implied or assumed.  I am trying to achieve that same end here.  I am going to be creating an entire XML file by the time this program is done and I would rather not have the xmlns attribute for absolutely every element in it.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Yeah, you don't want to explicitly provide the xmlns attribute. Just add the XNamespace as you already did in your query. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the loop as follows, providing the namespace. This should create the nodes as you want them.

```
foreach (var now in targetDirectory)
{
    now.Add(new XElement(
        wixNS + "Directory",
        new XAttribute("Id", fileVariable.Directory.Name));
}
```

I am presuming here that `wixNS` is an instance of [`XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx), such as:

```
XNamespace wixNS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi";
```

I am not sure why the indenting is not working.

Comment: Thank you.  That fixed the namespace issue.  But how do I improve the formatting of the output.  All elements created in this loop are just placed on one line

Comment: @Update - I already have that included with my writer.  I will add the code for my writer to the original post.

Comment: @Adkins: Not sure why that doesn't work. Perhaps ask new question so you can get some others to weigh in on this particular problem.